# Delta-Epsilon proof of $\lim_{n\to \infty} r^n = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

Hey I've been having some trouble figuring out this problem. Not sure what to do with the restriction on $r$, or really how to go about writing it formally. Our professor assigned this as a problem but its not even mentioned Epsilon Delta Proofs aren't even mentioned in our textbook.

Give an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} r^n = 0$$ 
when $|r|<1$ and $r^n$ is divergent when $|r|>1$.

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: You should go and ask your profs what he/she supposes you to do if you don't even know the definition.

Comment: You've never been taught epsilon-delta proofs and now you're being asked to write one by a physics professor? This probably isn't something that can be taught here from scratch. You'll want to look them up in a good mathematics text.

Comment: As a rule, $n\to\infty$ usually requires an $\epsilon-N$ proof, not an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof (technically.)

Answer (score 1):

Saying that $\lim_{n\to\infty}r^n=0$ (for $|r|<1$) is an abbreviation for a longer statement:

> For any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $m$ such that, for every $n\ge m$, the inequality
>   $$
> |r^n-l|<\varepsilon
> $$
>   holds when $l=0$.

There is no problem if $r=0$, so we can assume $r\ne0$. Since $|r|<1$, we have that $|r|\cdot|r|<|r|\cdot 1$, or $|r|^2<|r|$. From this we can continue and conclude (by induction) that $|r|^{n+1}<|r|^n$ for every positive integer $n$. This is the same as saying $|r^{n+1}|<|r^n|$. So, in order that the inequality above is satisfied, we just need to find $m$ such that $|r^m|<\varepsilon$

This is the same as requiring that $m\log|r|<\log\varepsilon$ or, since $|r|<1$ so that $\log|r|<0$,
$$
m>\frac{\log\varepsilon}{\log|r|}
$$
Such an integer surely exists. (The logarithm is in basis $e$ or any basis $>1$.)

Saying that $r^n$ diverges for $|r|>1$ means that you can find no number $l$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}r^n=l$ (with the definition above).

Hint: for $|r|>1$, we have $|r|^{n+1}>|r|^n$ for every positive integer $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Repeating a proof
I saw in
"What is Mathematics":

This proof is for
$0 < r < 1$;
for negative $r$,
use
$|r^n| = |(-r)^n|$.

Since $0 < r < 1$,
$r = \frac1{1+a}$
where
$a
=\frac1{r}-1
> 0
$.

By Bernoulli's inequality
(one form of which is
$(1+a)^n \ge 1+an$
for $a \ge 0$
and integer $n \ge 1$),
for $n \ge 1$,
$(1+a)^n
\ge 1+an
>an
$
so
$r^n
=\frac1{(1+a)^n}
< \frac1{an}
= \frac1{\left(\frac1{r}-1\right)n}
$.

This should make
completing your
$\delta-\epsilon$
proof easier,
and it doesn't need logs.

---

Proof of Bernoulli's inequality:

Since $1+a \ge 1+a$,
true for $n = 1$.

If true for $n$,
$(1+a)^{n+1}
=(1+a)^{n}(1+a)
\ge (1+na)(1+a)
=1+(n+1)a +a^2
> 1+(n+1)a
$.